# Subtotals in excel should repeat

Tags: excel

Below is my data in excelsheet :

```
RID  RNO   RCOST
----------------
11   2    78                                        
11   3    30                     
22   6    20               
22   8    34
```

Need to display the subtotal of RCOST grouped on RID as :

```
RID  RNO RCOST
----------------
11   2   108   
11   3   108   
22   6   54   
22   8   54
```

I am able to calculate the subtotals but unable to populate the same subtotal for all the rows in that particular group.
Please provide some inputs

Answer (score 1):

If you don't plan to keep the original *RCost* numbers, you will need VBA to collect the conditional sum based on *RID* then write that total into the *RCost* column for each *RID*. If you are planning on keeping the original *RCost* numbers then a simple [SUMIF](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SUMIFS-function-c9e748f5-7ea7-455d-9406-611cebce642b) or [SUMIFS function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SUMIFS-function-9DD6179E-CCED-41DD-AC38-08FDF5B929E5) in a new column should suffice. In an unused column to the right,

```
=sumif(A:A, A2, C:C)
```

Fill down as necessary.

Comment: I have more than 100K rows, filling down would be a tedious job. Please suggest me any work around